# how to autoincreament id value in jpa annotations with oracle db ? how to generate uuid values?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT_GROUP")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ContactGroup implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7161778136151592279L;
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@Column(name = "GRPOUP_ID")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="contactGroup",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },  targetEntity = Contact.class)
Set<Contact> contacts;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Contact implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7161778136151592279L;
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@Column(name = "CONTACT_ID")
Long id;

@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name="group", unique=true)
String group;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "GRPOUP_ID")
ContactGroup contactGroup;

}
```

Can you please tell me what I wrong in the above code not getting autoincreament

gives ORA-00001: unique constraint violated

When i run the test case again and again

And I how to generate the uuid value it was inserted in blank vlaue in the first record

Can you please tell me Thanks in Advance

Comment: Oracle doesn't do "autoincrement" (i.e JPA strategy "IDENTITY"). You can use JPA "TABLE" strategy for GeneratedValue, or "SEQUENCE", so easily possible to stick to the JPA spec. The rest of your stuff is not JPA, Hibernate specific

Comment: I have commented these lines i.e
/*
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")*/
and tried with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) but gives the following error

 org.hibernate.MappingException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support identity key generation

Comment: And as I already said above ... Oracle RDBMS does not support "autoincrement" (aka JPA strategy IDENTITY). It will support TABLE or SEQUENCE, so use one of those!

Answer (score 0):

Due to you are working with Oracle DB, you could define and use a Oracle's Sequence to get a uuid doing something like next:

Create the sequence in your database,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "CONTACT_GROUP_SEQUENCE" 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 -- < here is your "autoincrement" simulation
MAXVALUE 999999999
MINVALUE 1 
NOCACHE 
ORDER
```

Map the sequence with 
`@SequenceGenerator` and use it inplace of `@GenericGenerator`

```
public class ContactGroup implements Serializable
{

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CONTACT_GROUP_SQ", sequenceName = "CONTACT_GROUP_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 0)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "CONTACT_GROUP_SQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "GRPOUP_ID")
private Long id;
...
```

You can't find this and another examples about how to use TableGenerator with Oracle DB in  this [link to Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm).